# Center slice a responsive svg image on resize

Tags: css, html, svg, responsiveness

I have been trying to center slice the responsive Svg image on resize.

I have used `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"` to achieve the output but the image width doesn't retain the width my screen.

```css
body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%; 
 min-width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle; 
 margin: 0;
}


.bg-svg {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; left: 0; 
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  d="0px" y="0px"
     width="1920px" height="1080px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice" class="bg-svg">
  <rect fill="#DACFB9" width="1920" height="1080"/>
  <rect x="719" y="296" fill="#EF6544" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <rect x="1438" y="296" fill="#AFFF84" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <rect x="1" y="296" fill="#7AEEFF" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 841 557)" font-family="'GothamBlack'" font-size="60">MIDDLE</text>
  </svg> 
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve output like this [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/undefinedtoken/full/jbxEjb/)  but i dont want to use a background image.

Comment: Please post your relevant code on SO (use a Stack Overflow Snippet if necessary - its the document icon with `<>` in it). Regarding your question, all you need to do is change your `svg` element tag to this: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" class="bg-svg">` - without the `px` unit mostly but I also removed all the other extraneous things.

Comment: @somethinghere i tried but its still the same. i want it to be responsive and should get sliced from the center when you resize. As good as taking a background and give a cover keeping the background position center on both the axis.

Comment: As you might have read in my answer, thats because the provided example is using the SVG as a background-image. If you save out your svg and use it with `url()` then it;s as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem was that your SVG needed to have:

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

so that it fills the wrapper.  There was some other unnecessary CSS as well.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" class="bg-svg">
  <rect fill="#DACFB9" width="1920" height="1080"/>
  <rect x="719" y="296" fill="#EF6544" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <rect x="1438" y="296" fill="#AFFF84" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <rect x="1" y="296" fill="#7AEEFF" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 841 557)" font-family="'GothamBlack'" font-size="60">MIDDLE</text>
  </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for.  Thanks Paul.

Comment: Placing these values on the `svg` element is risky, as it breaks correct size detection. Not advised.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Using `"100%"` for this purpose is precisely how they were meant to be used.  Note that browsers treat the `width` and `height` attributes of `<svg>` elements slightly different than the same attributes on HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are trying to achieve and have linked to uses `background-image`. In order to make this work correctly, use this simplified `svg`. Make sure you have the `viewBox`, `xmls` and at least a `width` or `height` property (set as an integer without unit only). Then the `svg` will handle just like any other background-image. I cannot show this here as I cannot link from SO, but heres the amended SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <rect fill="#DACFB9" width="1920" height="1080"/>
    <rect x="719" y="296" fill="#EF6544" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <rect x="1438" y="296" fill="#AFFF84" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <rect x="1" y="296" fill="#7AEEFF" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 841 557)" font-family="'GothamBlack'" font-size="60">MIDDLE</text>
</svg>
```

We could simulate this background as such:

```css
svg {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <rect fill="#DACFB9" width="1920" height="1080"/>
    <rect x="719" y="296" fill="#EF6544" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <rect x="1438" y="296" fill="#AFFF84" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <rect x="1" y="296" fill="#7AEEFF" stroke="#D3D2D2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="482" height="482"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 841 557)" font-family="'GothamBlack'" font-size="60">MIDDLE</text>
</svg>
```

If you save this out as an SVG file, you can simply use `background-image`:

```
background-image: url(path/to/vector.svg) repeat 50% 50%;
```

Comment: i am not using it as a background image because i want to trigger few javascript animations with the svg element and transform wont work on Internet explorer 9.

Comment: @undefinedtoken you can give or take this answer, but you can't have your cake and eat it too. The example provided uses `background-image`, and works well because of that. You can write JS to try to control all this but that's it.

Comment: OP wants to manipulate the SVG with JS. Which he will not be able to do if the SVG is linked as an external image from `background-image`.